# SQLAlchemy Core - generating PostgreSQL SUBSTRING expression?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

The syntax for SUBSTRING in PostgreSQL is `SUBSTRING(<text_expr> FROM <i> FOR <j>)`. Any idea how to make SQLAlchemy core generate that? I'm trying `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func`, but that expects typically comma-separated notation. I don't see a built-in `Function` that addresses this. I'm not quite sure if `literal` or `text` would work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking through the SqlAlchemy tests](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/f572cdf7850b7a2ee6b7535b8129a76fa73496e6/test/dialect/postgresql/test_compiler.py#L881), I found that `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func.substring` compiles to `SUBSTRING` for `PSQL`:

```
    def test_substring(self):
        self.assert_compile(
            func.substring("abc", 1, 2),
            "SUBSTRING(%(substring_1)s FROM %(substring_2)s "
            "FOR %(substring_3)s)",
        )
        self.assert_compile(
            func.substring("abc", 1),
            "SUBSTRING(%(substring_1)s FROM %(substring_2)s)",
        )
```

`func.substring(str, from, [for])` is indeed what you want. It is "comma-delineated" because that's how Python methods

If you want to generate the SQL yourself, you could do something like `text("SUBSTRING('foo' FROM 1 FOR 2)")`, but I don't see why you would.