# Slicing filter criteria in SQL alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query with filter criteria that I would like checked against the slice of line 3. The HouseReport.location can contain characters as well as numbers. The query looks something like this.

```
query = dbsession.query(HouseReport).filter(
    HouseReport.ID == loan.loan_id, 
    HouseReport.location[:1].notin_(('8', '9'))
```

)

Is there a way to check if a slice of the filter criteria is not in 8 or 9 as seen on line 3? Thank you.

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: I'm using SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are simply comparing the first character, there are several options to implement it.

**Option-1:** [startswith(...)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.startswith)

```
...
filter(or_(
    HouseReport.location.startswith('8'),
    HouseReport.location.startswith('9'),
))
```

**Option-2:** SUBSTRING function

This is DB specific, and might need to be implemented differently depending on the underlying database. But SA seem to implement this for most databases (although not documented). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55173045/99594) for more information.

```
...
filter(~func.substring(HouseReport.location, 1, 1).in_(('8', '9')))
```